# In Python, Rename a file with the folder's name in batch

Tags: python-2.7, batch-processing

My overarching goal is to rename a file with the containing folder's name and move the renamed file to a new location. I am a Python beginner.

How I am stuck.
I am looping through the directory and searching for the folder names, but I don't know how to pull the name of the folder out to use as the name for the file.[This is what my filing system looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3IQa.jpg)  Within each of the folders is a file VOP.shp that needs to be renamed and moved or copied elsewhere.

```
#loop through path
#Convert desired name to string
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for name in dirnames:
        if name.endswith("batch"):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the files with the extension.shp using the following code:

```
import glob
glob("a_directory_name/*/*VOP.shp")
```